# UnboundLocalError for nested function NOT raised for attribute in python

Tags: python, nested-function

I've looked briefly through the couple of dozen qus on `UnboundLocalError` for nested functions in python, and I thought I understood, until I tried it with a custom class instance

```
def fn1():
    a = 1

    def fn1a():
        print(a)
        a += 1
        print(a)

    fn1a()


class B:
    v = 1


def fn2():
    b = B()

    def fn2a():
        print(b.v)
        b.v += 1
        print(b.v)

    fn2a()


fn2()  # prints 1 then 2
fn1()  # raises UnboundLocalError
```

Why doesn't the error get raised in `fn2`?

Comment: must read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't assign to a nonlocal name. You used one, but that's fine; you assigned one of its attributes, without changing what the name itself is bound to.

Note, this would work exactly the same if `b` was a list or dict and you modified one of its members.

Comment: FYI, someone has flagged your post as 'low quality'. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22279908).